# Добавить элемент в RecyclerView из DialogFragment

Tags: android, android-fragment, recyclerview, dialogfragment

Есть фрагмент, создающий диалог(AddingTaskDialog) и есть фрагмент(EventFragment), в котором есть RecyclerView. Из EventFragment вызывается AddingTaskDialog, вбиваются необходимые данные и нужно, чтобы по нажатию кнопки ОК диалога в  RecyclerView добавлялся элемент с введенными параметрами. Проблема в том, что никак не пойму, как мне передать данные от диалога AddingTaskDialog в EventFragment. Подскажите, пожалуйста.

**AddingTaskDialog:**

```
public class AddingTaskDialog extends DialogFragment {
private EditText etDate;
private Task task;
private static final String DIALOG_TASK_DATE = "DialogDate";
private static final int REQUEST_TASK_DATE = 0;

private AddingTaskListener addingTaskListener;

public interface AddingTaskListener {
    void onTaskAdding();

    void onTaskAddingCancel();
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try {
        addingTaskListener = (AddingTaskListener) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement AddingTaskListener");
    }
}

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    task = new Task();

    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setTitle(R.string.dialog_title);

    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    View container = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_task, null);

    final TextInputLayout tilTitle = (TextInputLayout) container.findViewById(R.id.tilDialogTaskTitle);
    final EditText etTitle = tilTitle.getEditText();

    TextInputLayout tilDate = (TextInputLayout) container.findViewById(R.id.tilDialogTaskTitleDate);
    etDate = tilDate.getEditText();

    final Spinner taskSpinner = (Spinner) container.findViewById(R.id.dialog_task_responsible_spinner);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> arrayAdapter = ArrayAdapter
            .createFromResource(getActivity().getBaseContext(), R.array.person, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    taskSpinner.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    tilTitle.setHint(getResources().getString(R.string.hint_task_title));
    tilDate.setHint(getResources().getString(R.string.hint_task_date));

    builder.setView(container);

    etDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (etDate.length() == 0) {
                etDate.setText(" ");
            }
            FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
            DatePickerFragment datePickerFragment = DatePickerFragment.newInstance(task.getTaskDate());
            datePickerFragment.setTargetFragment(AddingTaskDialog.this, REQUEST_TASK_DATE);
            datePickerFragment.show(manager, DIALOG_TASK_DATE);
        }
    });
    builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.dialog_ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            task.setTaskTitle(etTitle.getText().toString());
            task.setResponsible(taskSpinner.toString());
            addingTaskListener.onTaskAdding();
            dialogInterface.dismiss();
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.dialog_cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            addingTaskListener.onTaskAddingCancel();
            dialogInterface.cancel();
        }
    });
    AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
    alertDialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
        @Override
        public void onShow(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {
            final Button positiveButton = ((AlertDialog) dialogInterface).getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
            if (etTitle.length() == 0) {
                positiveButton.setEnabled(false);
                tilTitle.setError(getResources().getText(R.string.dialog_error_empty_title));
            }
            etTitle.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                    if (charSequence.length() == 0) {
                        positiveButton.setEnabled(false);
                        tilTitle.setError(getResources().getText(R.string.dialog_error_empty_title));
                    } else {
                        positiveButton.setEnabled(true);
                        tilTitle.setErrorEnabled(false);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

                }
            });
        }
    });

    return alertDialog;
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        return;
    }
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_TASK_DATE) {
        Date date = (Date) data.getSerializableExtra(EventDatePickerFragment.EXTRA_DATE);
        task.setTaskDate(date);
        updateDate();
    }
}

public void updateDate() {
    etDate.setText(Utils.getDate(task.getTaskDate().getTime()));
}
```

}

**EventFragment:**

```
public class EventFragment extends Fragment implements AddingTaskDialog.AddingTaskListener{
private Event event;
private static final String DIALOG_DATE = "DialogDate";
private static final String ARG_CARD_ID = "card_id";
private static final int REQUEST_DATE = 0;

private EditText mTitleField;
private EditText locationTitle;
private EditText description;
private Button eventDateButton;
private ImageView hideShowImage;
private int hideShowImageStatus = 0;
private RecyclerView rvTaskList;
private TaskListAdapter adapter;

public static EventFragment newInstance(UUID cardId) {
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putSerializable(ARG_CARD_ID, cardId);
    EventFragment eventFragment = new EventFragment();
    eventFragment.setArguments(args);
    return eventFragment;
}

public EventFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    UUID cardId = (UUID) getArguments().getSerializable(ARG_CARD_ID);
    event = EventLab.getEventLab(getActivity()).getEvent(cardId);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_event, container, false);
    mTitleField = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.card_title);
    eventDateButton = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.event_date);
    hideShowImage = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.hide_show_image);
    hideShowImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (hideShowImageStatus == 0) {
                rvTaskList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                hideShowImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_expand_less_black_36dp);
                hideShowImageStatus = 1;
            } else {
                rvTaskList.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                hideShowImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_expand_more_black_36dp);
                hideShowImageStatus = 0;
            }
        }
    });
    rvTaskList = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.rv_task);
    rvTaskList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    updateDate();
    mTitleField.setText(event.getTitle());
    mTitleField.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            event.setTitle(charSequence.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

        }
    });
    eventDateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
            EventDatePickerFragment dialog = EventDatePickerFragment
                    .newInstance(event.getEventDate());
            dialog.setTargetFragment(EventFragment.this, REQUEST_DATE);
            dialog.show(manager, DIALOG_DATE);

        }
    });
    //
    locationTitle = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.card_title);

    description = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.card_title);
    updateUI();
    return v;
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    updateUI();
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.fragment_event, menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_item_new_task:
            DialogFragment addingTaskDialog = new AddingTaskDialog();
            addingTaskDialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "AddingTaskDialog");
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
private void updateUI() {
    TaskLab taskLab = TaskLab.getTaskLab(getActivity());
    List<Task> tasks = taskLab.getmTasks();
    if (adapter == null) {
        adapter = new TaskListAdapter(tasks);
        rvTaskList.setAdapter(adapter);
    } else {
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        return;
    }
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_DATE) {
        Date date = (Date) data.getSerializableExtra(EventDatePickerFragment.EXTRA_DATE);
        event.setEventDate(date);
        updateDate();
    }
}

private void updateDate() {
    eventDateButton.setText(Utils.getDate(event.getEventDate().getTime()));
}

private void updateTaskDate() {

}

@Override
public void onTaskAdding() {
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Task added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onTaskAddingCancel() {
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Task don't added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

private class TaskListHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private Task task;
    private TextView taskTitle;
    private TextView taskDate;
    private Spinner responsible;
    private CheckBox checkBoxTask;
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> arrayAdapter;

    public TaskListHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        taskTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.task_title);
        taskDate = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.task_date);
        arrayAdapter = ArrayAdapter
                .createFromResource(getActivity().getBaseContext(), R.array.person, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        responsible = (Spinner) itemView.findViewById(R.id.task_responsible_spinner);
        checkBoxTask = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox_task);
    }

    public void bindTask(Task task) {
        this.task = task;
        taskTitle.setText(task.getTaskTitle());
        taskDate.setText(Utils.getDate(task.getTaskDate().getTime()));
        responsible.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    }
}

private class TaskListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TaskListHolder> {
    private List<Task> tasks;

    public TaskListAdapter(List<Task> tasks) {
        this.tasks = tasks;
    }

    @Override
    public TaskListHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.model_task, parent, false);
        return new TaskListHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(TaskListHolder holder, int position) {
        Task task = tasks.get(position);

        holder.bindTask(task);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return tasks.size();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того что бы вернуть данные с `DialogFragment` нужно при создании объявить родительский фрагмент:

```
DialogFragment addingTaskDialog = new AddingTaskDialog();
addingTaskDialog.setTargetFragment(EventFragment.this,ADDING_TASK_CODE);
addingTaskDialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "AddingTaskDialog");
```

затем с `DialogFragment`-а послать результат родительскому фрагменту:

```
private void sendResult(int resultCode, String data) {
        if (getTargetFragment() == null) {
            return;
        }
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.putExtra("data", date);
        getTargetFragment().onActivityResult(getTargetRequestCode(), resultCode, intent);
    }
```

и принять его в родительском фрагменте:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(requestCode == ADDING_TASK_CODE){
    //обработать данные с AddingTaskDialog
    }
}
```

у вас именно так же реализован `EventDatePickerFragment`